C# MongoDB - вызов GetCollection единожды за сеанс
Разбираюсь с работой драйвера MongoDb для C#. Для доступа к методам работы с коллекцией используется метод Database.GetCollection<type>("collection"). Можно ли вызвать этот метод 1 раз записав результат в переменную а затем ссылаться на него для работы с коллекцией?
Я заметил, что мне приходится часто вызывать метод GetCollection перед тем, как сделать несколько действий с коллекцией, что может негативно сказаться на потребляемой памяти.
Могу ли я вызвать GetCollection один раз за все время выполнения программы, а потом для изменения ее содержимого ссылаться к этому объекту постоянно? Можно ли сделать несколько запросов к одному объекту коллекции одновременно из разных потоков? Может ли это привести к непредсказуемому поведению?

Вообще это вроде бы вьюха. Наверное можно и в переменную поместить. Приведите больше кода - что вы ещё делаете с этой коллекцией.

@CrazyElf вызываю методы ReplaceOne, InsertOne, Find и тд

Уточните, какую именно библиотеку используете для работы с Монго. Т. к. и Mongo популярная СУБД, и C# - популярный язык, то для них вполне могут быть несколько разных библиотек.

Metanit. Цитата: "Стоит отметить, что реализация интерфейса IMongoCollection по умолчанию потокобезопасна, поэтому ее можно определить в приложении в качестве глобальной переменной или через IoC-контейнер и повторно использовать в различных частях приложения".

Можно включить логирование, чтобы видеть, какие именно запросы уходят в БД.

@AlexanderPetrov я использую MongoDB.Driver. Если вы разбираетесь в работе драйвера, пожалуйста подскажите, в какую сторону мне нужно смотреть чтобы отследить возможные утечки памяти при работе с драйвером. Можно ли как то более явно указать сборщику мусора о необходимости высвободить ресурсы, связанные с обработанным запросом к коллекции, типа FindAsync и ToListAsync?

@Stepan Нужно больше кода. Find не грузит коллекцию в память. А вот ToList грузит. Но опять же, если вы потом не будете использовать полученный List, он будет утилизирован сборщиком мусора. Нужно смотреть на ваш код, так это всё абстрактные разговоры. Проблема видимо в том, как вы оперируете своими объектами в программе, а не в БД,

Судя по тому, что пишут на английском SO нет никакой разницы, как вы это будете делать.

GetCollection doesn't load the collection, not even a Find() will. In fact, you'll have to start iterating the MongoCursor before anything is actually loaded from the database, and even then, it won't load the entire collection but only batches of configurable size.

Коллекция при этом не грузится, а просто выдаётся курсор, с которым вы дальше и оперируете. Если у вас при этом расходуется лишняя память, то дело не в GetCollection.
Про потокобезопасность - да:

The implementation of IMongoCollection<TDocument> ultimately provided by a MongoClient is thread-safe and is safe to be stored globally or in an IoC container.

